# Particle decay and momentum

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

Studying particle physics I had a doubt that I can't seem to find a solution:

> Is possibile in a particle decay to produce some particles with no momentum?

As an example: take the following decay

$$\Upsilon(4S) \rightarrow B+\overline{B} $$

where the particle $\Upsilon (4S)$ is produced by the collision of an electron an a positron beam with different energies (such as in the BaBar experiment), so that $\Upsilon(4S)$ is produced with some momentum.

Or as another example the three body decay

$$K^+ \rightarrow \pi^0 + e^+ + \nu_e $$

where $K^+$ has some momentum. Would it be possible in the laboratory frame to produce the $\pi^0$, for example, with no momentum?

Comment: In some frame, a product with momentum will have none: its rest frame.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, that's clear. But maybe I didn't make it clear: I want to know if in the laboratory frame could be possible!

Comment: What is so special about the lab frame? go to the rest frame of the pion, Lorentz transform the decaying Kaon, and you have a magic lab frame such that....

Comment: *"What is the minimum lab frame momentum of the kaon such that the pion cannot be produced at rest in the lab?"* would be a suitable homework question for a upper-division course in particle physics (for graduate students it would be a warm-up question.), and it thinking about it in those terms might give you a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a proton of energy E hitting another proton. The result is 3 protons and an anti-proton. What is the minimum energy for this to happen?

The answer is 7 times the rest energy of a single proton. But why?

Also consider why pair production doesn't happen in a vacuum even though its always energetically permitted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about that!